How to decode SAML response and get the values sent by Idp in ASP.NET Core Web API?
I am implementing SAML Single Sign-On and using idp initiated method for login request. After login, it redirect users to my ASP.NET Core Web API where I have my Post method Callback() through which I am expecting to decode the SAML and assign values like userId, email, firstName and lastName.
I also will add token to the response which I will send to my Angular code.
As of now I am able to pull SamlResponse but I am unable to decode and assign it to variables.
I tried decoding it by using ClaimsPrincipal, but that is assigning null values.
If any one have did the same thing and can put some light on it then it will be really appreciated.
Please find all the namespaces I am importing :
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Sustainsys.Saml2.Configuration;
using Sustainsys.Saml2.Saml2P;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2;

Attaching my Callback() :
[HttpPost]
[Route("Callback")]
public IActionResult Callback()
{
    var samlResponse = Request.Form["SAMLResponse"].ToString().Replace(" ", "+"); 

    if (samlResponse == null)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("SAML response is null");
        return Unauthorized("SAML response is null");
    }

    _logger.LogInformation("SAML response received: {@SamlResponse}", samlResponse);

    var samlPrincipal = User as ClaimsPrincipal;
    var userId = samlPrincipal.FindFirst("User ID")?.Value;
    var email = samlPrincipal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value;
    var firstName = samlPrincipal.FindFirst("First Name")?.Value;
    var lastName = samlPrincipal.FindFirst("Last Name")?.Value;
    var token = GenerateJwtToken(userId, email, firstName, lastName);

    return Ok(new { token, firstName, lastName, email, userId });
}

private string GenerateJwtToken(string userId, string email, string firstName, string lastName)
{
    var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("****2023Key"));
    var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

    var claims = new[]
    {
        new Claim("UserID", userId),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, userId),
        new Claim("FirstName", firstName),
        new Claim("LastName", lastName),
        new Claim("Email", email),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, email),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
    };

    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
        issuer: "Test.com",
        audience: "Test.com",
        claims: claims,
        expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), // Token expiration time
        signingCredentials: creds
    );

    return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
}

